# como usar la situación de un checkBox marcado, para usar como condicion de un IF.(JAVA)

Tags: java, checkbox

public class VentanaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel modelCombo = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
private DefaultListModel modelGustosDisponibles = new DefaultListModel();
private int itemCantidadGustosCombo = 0;
public VentanaPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
    initOtherComponents();
    fillLists();   
}                         
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroupTipoHelado = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jLabelHeladeriaCadore = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanelGeneral = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanelTipoDeHelado = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabelTipoDeHelado = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    botonVasito = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    botonCucurucho = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabelPote = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    botonCuarto = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    botonMedio = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    botonKilo = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    botonAlfajorHelado = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jPanelCantidadYCobertura = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabelCantidadDeGustos = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    comboCantidadGustos = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    chkBanio = new java.awt.Checkbox();
    jPanelSeleccionDeGusto = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jLabelSeleccionDeGustos = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanelGustosDisponibles = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    listaGustosDisponibles = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    botonAgregar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabelFlechaIn = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPanelGustosSeleccionados = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    listaGustosSeleccionados = new javax.swing.JList<>();
    botonQuitar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabelFlechaOut = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabelTotalAPagar = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    botonCancelar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    botonConfirmar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    botonImprimir = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabelResultado = new javax.swing.JLabel();

private void fillLists() {
    DefaultListModel<String> listModelGustosDisponobles = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(listModelGustosDisponobles);

    DefaultListModel<String> listModelGustosSeleccionados = new DefaultListModel<>();
    listaGustosSeleccionados.setModel(listModelGustosSeleccionados);
}

private void comboCantidadGustosActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

    itemCantidadGustosCombo = comboCantidadGustos.getSelectedIndex();
}                                                   

private void botonQuitarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    String gustosSeleccionados = listaGustosSeleccionados.getSelectedValue();
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    if (gustosSeleccionados == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Primero seleccione un gusto para quitar",
                "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        modelGustosDisponibles.addElement(gustosSeleccionados);
        modelGustosSeleccionados.removeElement(gustosSeleccionados);
    }
}                                           

private void botonCancelarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();

    botonVasito.setSelected(false);
    botonCucurucho.setSelected(false);
    botonAlfajorHelado.setSelected(false);
    botonCuarto.setSelected(false);
    botonMedio.setSelected(false);
    botonKilo.setSelected(false);

    comboCantidadGustos.setSelectedItem("Cantidad de gustos a definir");
    jLabelResultado.setText(" ");
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    modelGustosSeleccionados.removeAllElements();
    chkBanio.setState(false);
    chkBanio.setEnabled(false);

}                                             

private void botonVasitoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    comboCantidadGustos.removeAllItems();
    modelGustosSeleccionados.removeAllElements();
    modelCombo.addElement("  1 gusto");
    modelCombo.addElement("  2 gustos");
    modelCombo.addElement("  3 gustos");
    chkBanio.setEnabled(false);
    comboCantidadGustos.setModel(modelCombo);
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    cargarListaGustos();
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(modelGustosDisponibles);
}                                           

private void botonCucuruchoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    comboCantidadGustos.removeAllItems();
    modelGustosSeleccionados.removeAllElements();
    modelCombo.addElement("  1 gusto");
    modelCombo.addElement("  2 gustos");
    chkBanio.setEnabled(true);
    comboCantidadGustos.setModel(modelCombo);
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    cargarListaGustos();
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(modelGustosDisponibles);
}                                              

private void botonAlfajorHeladoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    comboCantidadGustos.removeAllItems();
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    modelCombo.addElement("  1 gusto");
    chkBanio.setState(false);
    chkBanio.setEnabled(false);
    comboCantidadGustos.setModel(modelCombo);
    modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Vainilla");
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(modelGustosDisponibles);
}                                                  

private void botonCuartoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    comboCantidadGustos.removeAllItems();
    modelGustosSeleccionados.removeAllElements();
    modelCombo.addElement("  1 gusto");
    modelCombo.addElement("  2 gustos");
    chkBanio.setState(false);
    chkBanio.setEnabled(false);
    comboCantidadGustos.setModel(modelCombo);
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    cargarListaGustos();
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(modelGustosDisponibles);
}                                           

private void botonMedioActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    comboCantidadGustos.removeAllItems();
    modelGustosSeleccionados.removeAllElements();
    modelCombo.addElement("  1 gusto");
    modelCombo.addElement("  2 gustos");
    modelCombo.addElement("  3 gustos");
    chkBanio.setState(false);
    chkBanio.setEnabled(false);
    comboCantidadGustos.setModel(modelCombo);
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    cargarListaGustos();
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(modelGustosDisponibles);
}                                          

private void botonKiloActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    comboCantidadGustos.removeAllItems();
    modelGustosSeleccionados.removeAllElements();
    modelCombo.addElement("  1 gusto");
    modelCombo.addElement("  2 gustos");
    modelCombo.addElement("  3 gustos");
    modelCombo.addElement("  4 gustos");
    chkBanio.setState(false);
    chkBanio.setEnabled(false);
    comboCantidadGustos.setModel(modelCombo);
    modelGustosDisponibles.removeAllElements();
    cargarListaGustos();
    listaGustosDisponibles.setModel(modelGustosDisponibles);
}                                         

private void botonConfirmarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    if (botonConfirmar.isSelected()){
        botonImprimir.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        botonImprimir.setEnabled(false);
    }
    String mensaje = "";
    if (botonVasito.isSelected()) {
        mensaje = "  $  60,00";
        jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
    } else {
        if (botonAlfajorHelado.isSelected()) {
            mensaje = "  $  40,00";
            jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
        } else {
            if (botonCuarto.isSelected()) {
                mensaje = "  $  120,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
            } else {
                if (botonMedio.isSelected()) {
                    mensaje = "  $  200,00";
                    jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
                } else {
                    if (botonKilo.isSelected()) {
                        mensaje = "  $  370,00";
                        jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
                    } else {
                        if (botonCucurucho.isSelected()) {
                            mensaje = "  $  110,00";
                            jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}                                              

private void botonAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String gustosDisponibles = listaGustosDisponibles.getSelectedValue();
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();

    if (gustosDisponibles == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Primero seleccione un gusto para agregar",
                "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        int cantidadGustosSeleccionados = modelGustosSeleccionados.size();
        if (cantidadGustosSeleccionados > itemCantidadGustosCombo) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Te quedan " + (cantidadGustosSeleccionados - itemCantidadGustosCombo - 1) + " gustos por elegir",
                    "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            modelGustosSeleccionados.addElement(gustosDisponibles);
            modelGustosDisponibles.removeElement(gustosDisponibles);
        }
    }
}                                            

private void botonImprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    DefaultListModel<String> modelGustosSeleccionados = (DefaultListModel<String>) listaGustosSeleccionados.getModel();
    botonImprimir.setEnabled(false);
    if (modelGustosSeleccionados.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Disculpe pero debe seleccionar al menos un gusto disponible para realizar el pedido", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    } else {
        if (modelGustosDisponibles.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Su helado posee los siguientes gustos seleccionados: " + modelGustosSeleccionados.toString(), "Información", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Pedido Confirmado. Retirar por mostrador: " + modelGustosSeleccionados.toString(), "Información", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

private class ManejaChecks implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void ActionPerformed(javax.swing.ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (botonCucurucho.isSelected()) {
                mensaje = "  $  130,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje); 
            } 
            else {
                mensaje = "  $  110,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
            }
    }

}

```
public void cargarListaGustos(){
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Mousse de Limón");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Frutilla a la Crema");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Quinotos al Whisky");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Chocolate con avellanas");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Dulce de Leche");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Sambayon con pasas");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Crema Rusa con nueces");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Crema Americana");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Granizado");
modelGustosDisponibles.addElement("Vainilla");
```

}

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

}
```

Comment: Empezando que tenemos un par de clases `checkbox` tendrás que especificar a cual te refieres, a la perteneciente a java.awt.Checkbox o a la javax.swing.JCheckBox.
En ambos tendrás que ponerlos 'a las casillas de verificacion'  a la escucha de poder lanzar los respectivos eventos.

Comment: swing (JCheckBox)

Comment: como se hace? no lo he visto !!

Comment: <br/>import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;         <br/>                                                     <br/>import java.util.ArrayList;<br/>
<br/>import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;<br/>
<br/>import javax.swing.JOptionPane;<br/>
<br/>import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel; <br/>                                                              <br/>solo estas librerias estoy usando......<br/>

Comment: Te lo pongo en una respuesta. ;)

Comment: ok perdon no me salio los altos de lineas

Comment: ok, donde pones la respuesta?

Comment: Si estás aplicando el listener al `JRadioButton`, le aplicas el método anterior `addActionListener()` a el, y en la condición al `JCheckBox` le aplicamos el método `isSelected()` para saber si está seleccionado o no.

Comment: no lo habia puesto antes, porque es larguisimo

Comment: No yo necesito, condiccionar al JRadioButton con un IF?

Comment: Es decir, yo aprieto cucurucho y cuando tildo el bañado en chocolate, me tira el precio cuando aprieto confirmación,  por eso en el evento de botonConfirmacion estoy poniendo un IF con cucurucho.isSelected() pero dentro tengo que poner otro If con chkBanio.setSelected(true) o chkBanio.setEnabled(true) o isState ? no se podes orientarme

Comment: Voy a editar mi respuesta, y te voy a dejar un ejemplo que acabo de hacer, al final de mi respuesta. Así lo verás más claro. ;)

Comment: Hola Gracias a todos, resolvi el problema por el cual no era tomado por neatBeans.

Comment: Hola Gracias a todos, resolví el problema por el cual no era tomado por neatBeans. Yo que un JCheckBox y establecí un CheckBox por error. Luego que me di cuenta, lo reemplace y fue tomada, la sentencia  IF(jchkBanio.isSelected()) {  ...... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que nuestras casillas de verificación, pertenecientes a  `javax.swing.JCheckBox` realicen una acción, los tendremos que poner a la escucha para poder lanzar el evento en cuestión.

```
JCheckBox botonCucurucho = new JCheckBox("Cucurucho");
botonCucurucho.addActionListener(new ManejaChecks());
```

Y se podrán manejar bien, desde una clase interna anónima o bien desde una clase aparte que implemente la `interfaz ActionListener`

---

**1)** Lo manejamos desde una clase interna anónima

```
JCheckBox botonCucurucho = new JCheckBox("Cucurucho");
botonCucurucho.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (botonCucurucho.isSelected()) {
                mensaje = "  $  130,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje); 
            } 
            else {
                mensaje = "  $  110,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
            }
        }});
```

---

2) Lo manejamos desde una clase independiente, preferiblemente interna donde creamos los checkbox.

```
JCheckBox botonCucurucho = new JCheckBox("Cucurucho");
botonCucurucho.addActionListener(new ManejaChecks());

private class ManejaChecks implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (botonCucurucho.isSelected()) {
                mensaje = "  $  130,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje); 
            } 
            else {
                mensaje = "  $  110,00";
                jLabelResultado.setText(mensaje);
            }
    }

}
```

---

**Edito**

Te dejo un ejemplo en el cual, presionamos un botón de radio y si tenemos marcado a la vez un checkbox pondrá un texto, y si desmarcamos el checkbox pondrá otro texto, en este caso será un precio.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PruebaRadioYCheck extends JFrame {

    public PruebaRadioYCheck() {
        this.setTitle("JCheckBox");
        this.setBounds(600,300,600,400);
        add(new LaminaCheckRadio());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PruebaRadioYCheck marco = new PruebaRadioYCheck();
        marco.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        marco.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class LaminaCheckRadio extends JPanel {
    private JRadioButton botonCucurucho, botonBombom;
    private JCheckBox chkBanio, chkOtro;
    private JLabel texto;
    String mensaje = "Prueba";

    public LaminaCheckRadio() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        texto = new JLabel(mensaje);
        texto.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 24));
        JPanel panelNorte = new JPanel();
        panelNorte.add(texto);
        add("North", panelNorte);

        ButtonGroup grupo = new ButtonGroup();
        botonCucurucho = new JRadioButton("Cucurucho");
        botonBombom = new JRadioButton("Bombom");
        grupo.add(botonCucurucho);
        grupo.add(botonBombom);
        JPanel panelSur = new JPanel();
        panelSur.add(botonCucurucho);
        panelSur.add(botonBombom);
        chkBanio = new JCheckBox("Check1");
        chkBanio.addActionListener(new ManejaChecks());
        chkOtro = new JCheckBox("Check2");
        panelSur.add(chkBanio);
        panelSur.add(chkOtro);
        add("South", panelSur);     
    }

    private class ManejaChecks implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(botonCucurucho.isSelected()) {
                if(chkBanio.isSelected()) {
                    mensaje = "  $  130,00";
                }else {
                     mensaje = "  $  110,00";
                }
            } 
            texto.setText(mensaje);
        }

    }

}
```

**Resultado**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: abrazos viejo. De 10, te pasaste de macanudo. Me lo imaginaba pero creo que sin un evento de Listener no lo podía hacer.

Comment: Aún amplié la respuesta y gracias a tí amigo. :)

Comment: no importa que el checkbox de llama chkBanio (de bañdo en chocolate). Cucurucho es un JRadioButton

Comment: le agrego evento en las propiedades del checkbox(en la interfaz) cuales?

Comment: A ver si te entiendo bien, el botonCucurucho es un JRadioButton??
Si ves que no lo tienes claro, agrega todo el código posible a tu pregunta editandola y lo vemos tranquilamente.

Comment: Si estás aplicando el listener al `JRadioButton`, le aplicas el método anterior `addActionListener()` a el, y en la condición al `JCheckBox` le aplicamos el método `isSelected()` para saber si está seleccionado o no.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79868/discussion-between-diego-l-o-l-and-whor).